# Different message types (XMLs) on one TIBCO queue?

Tags: jms, ibm-mq, tibco-ems

I am trying to implement an application(Java) which will subscribe to different message types (XMLs) from other different applications via TIBCO EMS. Each of these message types will have a specific purpose. I am of the opinion that I should have multiple queues with multiple subscribers in my application, however, the TIBCO guy is adamant that there should be only one queue where all of these messages will be published and I will have one subscriber and the subscriber then should have logic to different tasks based on the XML received.

Which approach is better? One with multiple queues and subscribers OR the one queue and one subscriber? Please let me know reasons for the choice.

Thanks!

-Naveen

Answer (score 2):

Use unique message header for each *type of xml* while sending the message. And use `message selectors / filters` while receiving the same, so that it can be *routed / delegated* to the respective handler based on the header value. This way, you will be able to handle different type of xml messages by single queue as well.

Answer (score 1):

In general, if the same application is reading all the messages, it is much cleaner for that application to have a single input queue instead of multiple input queues. With multiple then the application will need to have logic to know which order to process the queues and so on. With one input queue, the messaging system can deal with the order of the messages - whether FIFO or by priority etc, and the application can just read the next message and process it.